# Best way to draw circle in C using letters

Tags: c, algorithm, geometry

I want to draw a circle using (ASCII) letters like `+`, `-` or `*`. What is best algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Did you try [Midpoint circle algorithm on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() 
{
    int radius = 16;
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<=2*radius; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<=2*radius; j++)
        {
            double distance = sqrt((double)(i-radius)*(i-radius) + (j-radius)*(j-radius));
            if (distance>radius-0.5 && distance<radius+0.5)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
            else
            { printf(" ");}
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```